# mvc3 dropdownlist reload and set value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

In Edit view:
I am passing ViewBag list for the ddl

Controller:

```
 ViewBag.CountryList = new SelectList(db.Country, "CountryCode", "Desc");
```

in edit view:
    How do I assign the viewbag to the ddl and set the value that is coming from the model

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CountryCode) <- contains the Desc Value, currently just shows in a textbox!
```

thx!

Comment: use `@Html.DropDownListFor`. If you read the parameters that C# specifies you need, its self explanitory. The fact you have the selectList in the viewbag already means you've nearly done it all yourself already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use @Html.DropDownListFor. If you read the parameters that C# specifies you need, its self explanitory. The fact you have the selectList in the viewbag already means you've nearly done it all yourself already.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryCode, ViewBag.CountryList);
```

If that doesnt set the correct value for any reason, you can also use

```
 @Html.DropDownList("CountryCode", ViewBag.CountryList, new { @value = @Model.CountryCode });
```